# How to wait for xml response to load in rest assured

Tags: java, xml, testng, rest-assured

API responses currently we are working on are in xml format. We suspect our test cases in rest assured are failing because we are not really waiting for the response to receive completely.

Added a line to check status code but we get 200 everytime.

Any other possible solution to wait for the complete xml response to receive ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more information? How did you know RA not waiting for response?

Comment: Test cases were passing in local whereas failing in jenkins

Comment: Make sure that your server delivers the content of exactly the same size as stated in content-length header

Comment: We don't have content length header actually. We get 2 responses and compare them using compareXML to find the differences. In local, there are no differences whereas on jenkins, we are seeing differences in responses.

Comment: You have to have that header. Otherwise the client might have wrong understanding on when the content is completely delivered